# Java API for reading LAS(Log ASCII Standard) files?

Tags: java, log-ascii-standard

Is anyone having experience in reading LAS(Log ASCII Standard) Files using Java?

I found one Python library, but in our environment we are restricted to use Java.

https://lasio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question would better fit https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Please be careful before sending people to Software Recommendations SE. The site is moderated very strictly, even more strict than SO.  **If** you refer people there, please point out their [question guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) .

Answer (score 1):

Try this option, it's an Java API for read/write many different formats among others LAS.

> As of Q1/2018 Log I/O supports reading and writing of the following well log formats: DLIS, LAS2, LAS3, LIS, BIT, XTF, ASC, SPWLA and CSV.

Also the given website provides an example for reading/writing an LAS file.
[Log I/O - Well log access library](https://petroware.no/logio.html)

Comment: It ain't opensource. You have to pay to be have access to the LAS reader package.